# Update table right after the record is retrieved in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a SQL query which retrieves all the records which have [STAT_TG]   = 'INSERTED' and convert the output to a XML file finally update all the records which have [STAT_TG]   = 'INSERTED' to [STAT_TG]   = 'DELETED'. My requirement is to update the [STAT_TG] field right after the record is retrieved to the XML.
My query is as below.

```
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT  
PXTXTP,
PXTXCD,
PXACCD
    
FROM [RecordDetails].[dbo].[Records]  
WHERE  [STAT_TG]   = 'INSERTED'
) AS "Transaction"

FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('DataArea') 



UPDATE [RecordDetails].[dbo].[Records]
SET [STAT_TG]  = 'DELETED'

FROM [RecordDetails].[dbo].[Records] 
WHERE  [STAT_TG]   = 'INSERTED'

 end
```

This table is updating from another system and it is always updating. For a development requirement this query is scheduled for 1 second. Therefore, sometimes when the flag is updating as [STAT_TG] = 'DELETED' records which are not retrieved also getting updated as DELETED and they are not coming to the output XML file.
Therefore can somebody help me to achieve this?

Comment: Why isn't what you have working?

Comment: It seems like you should be storing the ID's of the rows you are processing separately, and then should be using that to `UPDATE` the table, rather than assuming the rows are unchanged between your `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements. If I am reading through the lines correctly.

Comment: alternatively, you could use the reversed approach: `UPDATE...OUTPUT inserted.* INTO @table and generate the xml from @table` (from the output, i.e updated rows).

Comment: Hi @Larnu yes you are correct but how to I store the IDs of records which are retrieved from the table. Can you please show that?

Comment: With an `INSERT` or an `INTO`, @RasangaAbeykoon .

Comment: Hi @lptr  I saw that in a post unfortunately I'm new to SQL and don't have a idea how to do that. Can you show that as a answer?

Comment: ...@cetin-basoz answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming those fields' types were all varchar(10) here is a sample to do that:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
  (
    PXTXTP  VARCHAR(10)
  , PXTXCD  VARCHAR(10)
  , PXACCD  VARCHAR(10)
  );

UPDATE [RecordDetails].[dbo].[Records]
SET    [STAT_TG]='DELETED'
OUTPUT
  inserted.PXTXTP, inserted.PXTXCD, inserted.PXACCD
INTO @data
WHERE  [STAT_TG]='INSERTED';

SELECT *
FROM
       (SELECT PXTXTP, PXTXCD, PXACCD FROM @data) AS "Transaction"
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('DataArea');
```